# Get device make/model from disc drive, hard drive, etc

Tags: python, python-2.7, hardware, hardware-interface, hardware-id

In Python 2, I'm looking to get the make/model of a device, such as an Ethernet card, hard drive, CD/DVD/BD drive, etc. I have no idea where to start, and the closest thing a Google search can come up with is detecting when a disc is inserted into a drive or getting the name of a USB device.

For example, I'd look to retrieve a name such as `ST1500DM003-9YN16G` (this is a HDD) or `VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter` (this is an Ethernet adapter) from the system. Requiring admin privileges isn't an issue, as the program that this'll be used in requires admin privs for other operations anyway.

Comment: I don't know how exactly to do this, but you could probably get most/all of this info from the command line, and Python can get the output of commands. How to do that is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215), but I'm not quite sure what commands would have to be run, depends on the OS I'm sure. Hope this is a start.

Comment: As far as I know, there's no cross-platform library that wraps all of this up. There are two different Windows-specific ways to get this info, one Mac-specific way, one Linux-specific way, and one semi-generic POSIX (everything but Windows) way. All of them can be accessed via either running a command-line tool, opening and reading a file in a special location, or making a web service request, but there are probably libraries on PyPI that wrap up the more painful ones.

Comment: @abarnert If you can point me to the POSIX and Windows ways, that'd be really helpful.

Comment: For Googlers, on Windows, the following block will return a NULL-separated list of all device names:
`>>>import win32file` 






`>>>win32file.QueryDosDevice(None)`